# If our body is the church, why should we go to a place called church?

Tags: sabbath, church-local, church-universal

In the old testament days, God asked Moses to construct a place for Him to reside.

> Exodus 25:8 (NKJV)
> And let them make Me a sanctuary, that I may dwell among them

But in New testament, We read that our own body is the Temple of Holy Spirit.  We read it in a number of places when Paul writes to the Corinthians,

> 1 Corinthians 6:19 (NKJV)
> Or do you not know that your body is the temple of the Holy Spirit who is in you, whom you have from God, and you are not your own?
>
> 1 Corinthians 3:17 (NIV)
> If anyone destroys God’s temple, God will destroy that person; for God’s temple is sacred, and you together are that temple.
>
> 1 Corinthians 6:19 (NIV)
> Do you not know that your bodies are temples of the Holy Spirit, who is in you, whom you have received from God? You are not your own;
>
> 2 Corinthians-6:16
> For you are the temple of the living God

However in Hebrews we have Assembly should not be forsaken.

> Hebrews 10:25 (NKJV)
> ..not forsaking the assembling of ourselves together, as is the manner of some, but exhorting one another, and so much the more as you see the Day approaching.

If our body is the Church, What is the place when we gather on the Sabbath day, as we call it too as Church? Is that just an assembly? Is that just enough to keep our body Holy and ignore the gathering? If God lives in the Church, our Body, Is the congregation is needed?

Comment: Don't confuse the popular usage of the word versus the biblical meaning. The popular meaning is a place of worship. The biblical meaning is "called-out ones," the people, not the building.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Our bodies are not the church.

The verse in 2 Corinthians that you quote says that our bodies are *temples*. In context this is saying that we (rather than a building) are the dwelling place of the Holy Spirit. In the OT his presence would rest in the temple and that was considered his dwelling among his chosen people. In the NT this took a new form -- the vail in the temple was torn asunder -- and his spirit actually lives within those who have been called according to his purpose.

It is only together in fellowship that we make up the church. Believers collectively are a body: the church.

Answer (score 5):

> **Hebrews 10:24-25** (NIV)
>
> 24 And let us consider how we may spur one another on toward love and
>   good deeds, 25 not giving up meeting together, as some are in the
>   habit of doing, but encouraging one another—and all the more as you
>   see the Day approaching.

The point of meeting together is so that we can learn as Iron sharpens Iron, and spur one another toward love and good deeds.

> **Acts 2:44-46**  (NIV)
>
> 44 All the believers were together and had everything in common. 45
>   They sold property and possessions to give to anyone who had need. 46
>   Every day they continued to meet together in the temple courts. They
>   broke bread in their homes and ate together with glad and sincere
>   hearts,

Live not as if you are a part of this world, but commune together with other believers so that the love of God can flourish among you.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the place when we gather on the Sabbath day, as we call it too as Church?

What we call it is simply modern English usage, which tends to create lazy versions for commonly used long expressions.  For instance:

- The "microwave" in our kitchens isn't a microwave, it is a "microwave oven".
- The "remote" on our couches isn't remote, it is a "remote control device".
- The "cell" in our pockets isn't a cell, it is a "cellular telephone receiver".
- The "satellite" on our roofs isn't a satellite, it is a "satellite dish antenna".
- The "church" we go to isn't a church, it is a "church building" or "church meeting place".

Answer (score -1):

In every book of the bible the authors are concerned with law.  God's law is a perfect law of liberty.  This liberty is both spiritual and physical.  The word Church is synonymous with Assembly and Congregation.  These are assemblies of law, where the judges, elders, leaders, and priests come together to settle matters of law, to teach the law, and so on.  The worship of Abba father was done through obedience of the law, in keeping the feasts and holy days, in the context of seeking first his righteousness and his kingdom through upholding the cause of the innocent, the fatherless and the widow, the stranger and the levite.

This is seen historically as well as scripturally.  Scripturally we see the psalmists declaring the word/law of Abba Father in the assemblies.  We see various bible heroes, such as Joseph, Daniel, Esther, Moses, Joshua, and others risen by Abba father to places of influence and power to uphold the law of God, called by James the perfect law of liberty.  Jesus was especially interested in teaching the law, as were Paul and Peter.  Even in Hebrews, having found fault with "them" (the previous priesthood) Abba father gave Christ the mantle of High Priest, so that he might administrate the law from then forward as both High Priest and High King of the Kingdom of God.

Historically, we can examine the Magna Carta the history of English Common Law from which the American Declaration of Independance is also derived, declaring the Law of God to be the Common Law of the Land, that there is no one above the law, that a man must pay his debts, act with honor and do no harm.

Therefore, I propose to anyone who will listen the sentiments of Thomas Jefferson, who in the letters where he coined the phrase "seperation of church and state" he expressed plainly and I believe correctly that "we the people" are the church.

The Temple, is with Christ.  Modern corporate institutions called churches are not "Churches" as expressed in scripture.  Rather, they are legal entities created to limit individual liability, and in the case of modern churches registered as corporate charities, to, in exchange for agreeing with the state to various conditions, be exempt from paying taxes, which I personally believe to be a grave error on the part of 'we the people' who serve Christ, seeing as so much of the scripture has to do with law.

This is my first answer on stackexchange and I intend to edit it in the future with quotes and citations, however to do it all in one sitting for my part at this time is not feasible.  Thank you and bless you all.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: This answer lacks focus, covering multiple issues but not dealing with the actual question which was posed.